# Any game like TuxKartRacing for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I like this game TuxKartRacing and want other games like this. Please help me.

I already use [gbrainy](https://wiki.gnome.org/gbrainy), [Torcs](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/index.php), [Neverball](http://neverball.org/), [0ad](http://play0ad.com/) and [metal blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_Wars) solid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try These car racing games.

[**3D rally racing** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/trigger-rally/).

[**TORCS** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/torcs/).

[Vdrift](http://www.playdeb.net/software/VDrift)

[Speed Dreams](http://www.playdeb.net/software/Speed%20Dreams)

Comment: already used torcs

Comment: 3d rally is also fine but....

Answer (score 0):

The game is already in Ubuntu.

To install it, press Ctrl-Alt-t. In the terminal that opens,
issue the command,

```
sudo apt-get install supertuxkart
```

Or you may want to use the Software Center to install this game.

Official website of the game is [here.](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i know that it is on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Supertuxkart is like a premium version of TuxKartRacing, give it a try :)

http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/Discover

Comment: i already use that!